# Imagemagick non-conforming drawing primitive definition `,' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3169

Tags: php, imagick

This appears to be an accent-related problem.  The code has worked perfectly for over a million photo watermarks, but as soon as there's an accent in the watermark (in this case e acute, é [and yes, I have double checked that that's what the character is]) it spits out that error.

I'm using Myriad Pro ttf file, and I've checked and it does contain that character.

Is this a known problem?  If so, what's the workaround?

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont('MyriadPro-Regular.ttf');
$draw->annotation(100, 100, 'é');
$photo->drawImage($draw);
```

Comment: Can you add a one-liner that recreates this problem?

Answer (score 1):

(apologies, this is not an answer yet, but is far too long for the comment box)

> Is this a known problem?

Nope.

The only thing I can think would cause it is trying to use a non-utf8 character, which the SVG renderer doesn't like. Although it looks like a normal acute accent e, and you've said you've checked, please could you double-check by showing the output of this function:

```
function showRawCharacters($result) {
    $resultInHex = unpack('H*', $result);
    $resultInHex = $resultInHex[1];
    $resultSeparated = implode(', ', str_split($resultInHex, 2)); //byte safe
    echo $resultSeparated;
}
```

For the string you're using.

Also, please can you confirm that you're not using setlocale anywhere in your code.

For the record, your code works fine, so I doubt that it's going to be something wrong with your code. It's more likely to be something in the environment, library version or general non-obvious thing.

*Edit*
I strongly suspect that something in your code somewhere altering the locale, which is not safe to do, which is why I think it ought to be [removed from PHP](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?7,1172968)

Please can you run:

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, "0"));
```

Immediately before the `->annotation` line and add the results to your question.

Comment: c3, a9NULL.

I now know that the script only fails when called as part of my image uploader.  If I call it separately (either from a browser or the CLI), it works.  Weird.  And if I replace that character with a regular "e" it works fine across the board.

Comment: @Codemonkey Can you try the setlocale thing I've just added?

Comment: @Codemonkey can you answer your own question if you've figured it out please?

Comment: I can't, the problem went away after I changed the text to non-accented version, and remained away when I changed it back TO accented version.

Comment: I can only assume that although the character looked regular there was something a bit screwy about it.  When I ran it through various online tests it said it was fine, but I'd copied and pasted it from the front end of the website rather than the database, and maybe chrome had "cleansed" the character or something.

Comment: i have ImagickException non-conforming drawing primitive definition php and i have after this line  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'); and i deleted it and its works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var rolePath = `image Over ${role.outX},${role.outY},${role.outW},${role.outH},"${role.rolePath}"`;
```

add image Over

```
gm(backimgPath).draw(rolePath)
```